# How does one handle a continuous variable regressed on a low count binary?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

Suppose I have a continuous variable $Y$ that takes values in $\mathbb{R}$. Assume that $X \in \{0,1\}$ with only around 25$\%$ of the $X$ variables being $1$. Running a least squares regression here results in an $R^2$ value of near $0$. What kind of analysis can we do to see if there is a relation between $Y$ and $X$ being equal to $1$? Does Poisson regression work?

Comment: You're basically telling us $Y$ falls into two groups and their means are essentially the same.  Changing the model is unlikely to change that result.  It will come down to *what kind* of relationship you are looking for.

Comment: I am looking for a test to see if $X$ can influence $Y$. Would linear regression be invalid here due to assumptions?

Comment: There is no test of influence, only tests of association. You need to supply more information about how $Y$ varies with $X$ before anyone could offer an opinion concerning the applicability of linear regression.

Answer (score 0):

Poisson regression will not work.  Poisson regression is useful when the dependent variable is a count.  You have a continuous dependent variable.

Your regression seems appropriate and it tells you what linear regression tells you: The means of Y are not very different when X = 0 or X = 1.  You could also do a t-test, it is equivalent.

If you are looking for some other relationship (e.g. the variances of Y are different when X = 0 or X = 1) then there are tests for that, but if you are just trying to find some sort of difference (any sort will do!) then I suggest graphing the data.

If N is small (say, less than 100 or so) then you can do a strip plot (essentially a scatter plot) perhaps with some jittering.  If N is larger, a parallel box plot may be better.

However, when looking for "any sort of difference" I'd be very careful about any statistical tests as you don't have a well formed null hypothesis.

Comment: Re "Poisson regression will not work:"  William Gould of Stata has a remarkably different opinion.  Whether one agrees or not, it's worth being aware of: https://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend/.

Comment: That certainly is interesting.  Personally, I would take logs only for substantive reasons, not statistical ones. I wonder how robust (linear) regression does and whether Stata has that.  (I know nothing of Stata's capabilities).